# Dynamically allocate Random Eigen VectorXd

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

Allocating a randomized VectorXd in eigen is done as follows:

```
VectorXd z = VectorXd::Random(10000);
```

However, I am not sure how to allocate the same Vector dynamically:

```
VectorXd* z = new VectorXd::Random(10000); // error: expected type-specifier
```

since `VectorXd` is a `typedef`. I can use another constructor, however I suspect this is uncessary and inefficient:

```
VectorXd* z = new VectorXd(VectorXd::Random(10000)); // compiles
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Eigen::VectorXd` is a container that will dynamically allocate the needed memory for its own contents (the array of elements), so all of the following will work:

```
VectorXd* z1 = new VectorXd(VectorXd::Random(10)); // compiles
std::cout << "z1:\n" << z1->transpose() << "\n\n";

VectorXd* z2 = new VectorXd(); // also compiles
z2->setRandom(10);
std::cout << "z2:\n" << z2->transpose() << "\n\n";

VectorXd* z3 = new VectorXd(); // compiles as well
*z3 = VectorXd::Random(10);
std::cout << "z3:\n" << z3->transpose() << "\n\n";
```

This is true for most of the Eigen objects with the exception of those whose size in not dynamic (e.g. `Eigen::Vector3d`).